# Create slug with relationships

Tags: symfony, slug

I would like to create a slug with the combinations of relations of external tables. I would like to take 2 values ​​from a table and another value from un'atra table. I tried to do this but I do not understand how to add two values ​​and another table .. and it is required to have the fields (in my case empty)?

```
 /**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="profile")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * */
private $utente;

/**
 * @Gedmo\Slug(handlers={
 *      @Gedmo\SlugHandler(class="Gedmo\Sluggable\Handler\RelativeSlugHandler", options={
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationField", value="utente"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="relationSlugField", value="nickname"),
 *          @Gedmo\SlugHandlerOption(name="separator", value="-")
 *      })
 * }, separator="-", updatable=true, fields={"empty"})
 * @ORM\Column(length=64, unique=true)
 */
private $slug;
```

I would also email as well as username field,and add another relationField

Comment: I opened a pull request that would allow to use several values from a relationship: https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/pull/1734